# fastify-cors plugin with TypeScript: 'origin' is not defined

Tags: typescript, fastify

Trying to set up CORS for fastify vai the fastify-plugin in a fairly strict typescript environment. The docs showing the async configuration https://github.com/fastify/fastify-cors#configuring-cors-asynchronously

```
import fp from 'fastify-plugin';
import cors from 'fastify-cors';

export default fp(async (fastify) => {
  fastify.register(cors, () => (callback: any): void => {
    let corsOptions;
    if (/localhost/.test(origin)) {
      corsOptions = { origin: false };
    } else {
      corsOptions = { origin: 'www.mywebsite.com' };
    }
    callback(null, corsOptions);
  });
});
```

The error I get is

```
'origin' is not defined.eslintno-undef
Cannot find name 'origin'.ts(2304)
```

How do I define origin?

If I try the non-async example from the docs origin is still undefined

```
import fp from 'fastify-plugin';
import cors from 'fastify-cors';

export default fp(async (fastify) => {
  fastify.register(cors, {
    origin: (origin, callback) => {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      console.log(origin); //<======== undefined
      if (/localhost/.test(origin)) {
        callback(null, true);
      } else {
        callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'), false);
      }
    },
  });
});
```

Comment: The if statement `if (/localhost/.test(origin)) {` is using a variable origin which is not defined. If you define that variable you won't get the error.

Comment: from the example, in the documentation, I don't understand how to define origin